# Live preview visual block insert mode in vim?

Tags: vim

In vim, I can hit `Ctrl-v 4j shift-I hello ESC` to prepend `hello` to 4 lines of text.

However, while I am typing `hello`, I only see myself typing on the *first* line. Is there any way to make it so I see myself typing on all four lines at once? (like in the equivalent mode in, say, Textmate, or emacs' cua-mode)

Comment: You could try a multiple cursors plugin. https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors. (I have never used it). There are links to a lot of other ones in the readme.

Comment: I think this is a cool feature. :-D. Only you know, what would happen... magic!!

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way, for several reasons:

- the parallel screen update would be slower (think of vi's heritage: slow terminal over low-bandwidth connection)
- more difficult to implement (think of underlying autocmd events, potential popup menu, etc.)
- inconsistency with other commands (such as `4a` or `3o`), which also only show the first edit, and duplicate the entered text after insert mode is left

There is probably a way to implement such in Vimscript (similar to what the mentioned *multiple cursors* plugins do), but it would probably be hard to get right under all circumstances.